# Orchard: Programmatically over-riding the shapes of "Admin" in custom modules

Tags: orchardcms

I have a requirement where i need to override this specific shape in my custom module.
Core/Contents/Views/Admin/CreatableTypeList.cshtml

I have the option of copying it over to my theme but the over-riding functionality is making more sense within the module so that once the module is activated the functionality would come into play.

I would be thankful for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a dependency on the module that has the templates you want to override.

Comment: I tried exactly as you mentioned. Added the dependency of "Contents" in my custom module "Orchard.SiteManagement" and placed overridden shape in Views but still it is not picking up the correct shape.


I then renamed the original shape filename to see the order it was picking up the shapes and it showed me this:

Comment: ~/Themes/TheAdmin/Views/Contents/admin/CreatableTypeList.cshtml
~/Themes/TheAdmin/Views/CreatableTypeList.cshtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Contents/admin/CreatableTypeList.cshtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/CreatableTypeList.cshtml
~/Core/Contents/Views/admin/CreatableTypeList.cshtml
~/Modules/Contents/Views/admin/CreatableTypeList.cshtml
~/Themes/Contents/Views/admin/CreatableTypeList.cshtml
...
...
...
~/Modules/Orchard.SiteManagement/Views/CreatableTypeList.cshtml
...
...

~/Core/Contents/Views/CreatableTypeList.cshtml
...

Comment: Right: it has `~/Modules/Orchard.SiteManagement/Views/CreatableTypeList.cshtml` in there. Does that not solve your problem?

Comment: no it is not solving the problem because before it tries to pick up the shape from my custom module it uses the one available from Contents module. Kindly see the above post where it first tries to get it from TheAdmin then from MyTheme and right after that it uses the shape from Contents. Somewhere down below it has that entry where it tries to find the shape in custom module. Once i rename the original shape file it starts picking up shape from my module. Kindly guide what else i can try.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, you'll probably have to introduce an alternate through a shape table provider then. Template overriding between modules is not a scenario that has been given much thought about.

Comment: i tried doing exactly as you mentioned but the debugger never hits for any of the functions OnCreating, OnCreated, OnDisplaying, OnDisplayed for 'builder.Describe("CreatableTypeList")' as well as builder.Describe("Admin_CreatableTypeList"). For now im thinking to move the shape to my own theme. But please let me know if you have any other alternate solution in your mind. Thanks.

Comment: That's not normal. The shape table provider should definitely get hit. Something weird is going on here, but I'm afraid I can't guess what without attaching a debugger and digging.